# Spring Session changed the cookie value causing HTTP 302 on succeeding requests

Tags: spring, session-cookies, spring-session

Migrating from servlet container HTTP session to spring session has caused HTTP 302 after successful login. I've got an HTTP 200 on first request after login, but succeeding requests seem redirected to login page again. Cannot debug on succeeding requests as it seems not able to reach through the servlet where I put some breakpoint.

Right now, we are using spring session 1.3.5 version. And have noticed that in spring's SessionRepositoryFilter, it replaced the original request cookies (e.g. servlet container) to the value from spring session. I am not sure if this is the root cause of the issue. If it is, can someone suggest how to resolve it? Or is it related to some sort of missing configuration?

Here's the current setup based on the guide from spring session: [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/)

Spring session XML configuration:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<bean class="org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration"/>
<bean id="hazelcastInstance" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.CustomHazelcastProvider.getInstance"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer">
    <property name="cookieName" value="JSESSIONID"/>
    <property name="cookiePath" value="/"/>
    <property name="domainNamePattern" value="^.+?\.(\w+\.[a-z]+)$"/>
</bean>
```

Reference of spring XML configuration in web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Registration of spring session repository filter in web.xml. As describe in the guide, I placed it as the first entry of the filter chain.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSessionRepositoryFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have been working on it for days now and don't know yet how to fix it. Will appreciate any help or suggestion that you can advise.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please note that Spring Session 1.3.x has reached its end of life, meaning that there are no further maintenance releases or security patches planned.
Please migrate to a supported branch as soon as possible. The supported versions are 2.2.x, 2.3.x and 2.4.x

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana, thank you so much for the comment. We cannot upgrade 2.x.x version due to current library dependency issue. Changing it would need to have other dependencies be changed as well. I just replaced the HTTP session strategy from cookie to header based. So far, my application is working now as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue using spring session `HeaderHttpSessionStrategy`.

Steps I've made:

1. In my spring session XML configuration, I removed the entry related to cookie serializer to change the cookie name.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer">
   <property name="cookieName" value="JSESSIONID"/>
   <property name="cookiePath" value="/"/>
   <property name="domainNamePattern" value="^.+?\.(\w+\.[a-z]+)$"/>
</bean>
```

2. By default, spring session uses `CookieHttpSessionStrategy`. Added below entry in spring session XML configuration.

```
<bean id="httpSessionStrategy" class="org.springframework.session.web.http.HeaderHttpSessionStrategy"/>
```

3. Then on every request, I am passing **x-auth-token** in the http request header.

After the said change, the application works as expected. Able to login without an issue.

Hope this solution will help others who have encountered the same issue.